# AD_NewUser parameters Powershell error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate the creation of new AD Users. A snippet of the offending code is below;

```
    New-ADUser -GivenName "$firstname" `
-Surname $surname -DisplayName ($firstname + ' ' + $surname)  `
-UserPrincipalName ($firstname + '.' + $surname + $email) -EmailAddress ($firstname + '.' + $surname + $email) -Department $department -HomePhone $phonenumber -AccountPassword $plainpassword  -ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 -Enabled 1 -Fax "OMITTED" -HomeDirectory "OMITTED" + $firstname + "." + $surname "\My Documents" -HomeDrive "M:" -Manager $manager -OtherAttributes @{'title'=$jobtitle}
```

When I input $firstname as Owen, I get the following error;

```
    New-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Owen'.
At C:\Users\ryan.hargreavesadmin\Desktop\NewUser.ps1:24 char:1
+ New-ADUser -GivenName $firstname `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUs 
   er
```

What obvious thing am I likely missing?

Comment: Please show the entirety of your `New-ADUser` command as the code you have shown is likely not the cause of your error.

Comment: Updated, I was parameterising so that personal info wasn't released in this

Comment: Apologies, copying it over I saw my syntax error!

Answer (score 0):

Try to double-quote the variable given
like so:

```
$firstname = Read-Host 'Enter first name'
New-ADUser -GivenName "$firstname" ` #Script continues for other parameters
```

Comment: I've got the same issue with double quotes I'm afraid.

Comment: Placing the Variable in quotes will not change anything. `Read-Host` will return a string to save in that variable. Then using that variable for a parameter in a cmdlet/function will take the fully expanded value, without need for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is going to be a space in one of values that you are passing to a parameter. The substring before the space was used as the value for a parameter and there wasn't another parameter to define by position for what was left over.

An example would be `-HomeDirectory John Owen + $firstname + "." + $surname "\My Documents"` In this the value of `HomeDirectory` will just be `John` and the rest will try to use position to fill the next parameter.

If you enclose your parameter values in double quotes and rely on variable interpolation rather than building strings with the `+` operator it is easier to avoid these issues as the entire value will always be passed to the parameter.

With the example it would look like: `-HomeDirectory "John Owen$firstname.$surname\My Documents"`

To apply this to all of your code would look like this:

```
New-ADUser -GivenName "$firstname" `
-Surname $surname -DisplayName "$firstname $surname"  `
-UserPrincipalName "$firstname.$surname$email" `
-EmailAddress "$firstname.$surname$email"
-Department $department `
-HomePhone $phonenumber `
-AccountPassword $plainpassword `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 `
-Enabled 1 `
-Fax "OMITTED" `
-HomeDirectory "OMITTED$firstname.$surname\My Documents" `
-HomeDrive "M:" `
-Manager $manager `
-OtherAttributes @{'title'=$jobtitle}
```